# Android studio 2.2.2 Gradle project refresh failed

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle

I have installed Android studio 2.2.2 in Ubuntu14.04 LTS 32 - bit machine along with **OpenJDK8**. And it is installed successfully.

But when i create a project or importing sample project it showing => Gradle project refresh failed.

```
Error:Process 'command '/home/paradigm/ANDROIDSTUDIO/android-studio/jre/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

After updating JDK location with embedded/jvm it not changed. I did re-installed studio also. Is there any problem with Studio 2.2.2 ..?

or anything we need to set properties ..? please any one can help on this? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace JRE from **"/home/paradigm/ANDROIDSTUDIO/android-studio/"** folder with JRE from your JDK. I had similar error with Android Device Monitor, and this, solved my problem.